# How to register a child component in Vue3 with typescript

Tags: typescript, registration, vuejs3

How have I to register the child component in Vue3 with typescript?
I use this example. NavBar must be registered.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar ref="child"/>
    <div class="container mt-6">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-12 column--align-center">
          <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from 'vue-class-component';
import Navbar from './components/core/Navbar.vue';
 
export default class App extends Vue {

}

</script>
<style>
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #f2f6fa;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it, in main.ts I have to register it:

```
import Navbar from "./components/core/Navbar.vue";

const app = createApp(App);

app.component('Navbar', Navbar);
```